# Pythonic enumeration of while loop

Tags: python, while-loop

Python has an elegant way of automatically generating a counter variable in `for` loops: the `enumerate` function. This saves the need of initializing and incrementing a counter variable. Counter variables are also ugly because they are often useless once the loop is finished, yet their scope is not the scope of the loop, so they occupy the namespace without need (although I am not sure whether `enumerate` actually solves this).

My question is, whether there is a similar pythonic solution for `while` loops. `enumerate` won't work for `while` loops since `enumerate` returns an iterator. Ideally, the solution should be "pythonic" and not require function definitions.

For example:

```
x=0
c=0
while x<10:
  x=int(raw_input())
  print x,c
  c+=1
```

In this case we would want to avoid initializing and incrementing `c`.

**Clarification:**

This can be done with an endless `for` loop with manual termination as some have suggested, but I am looking for a solution that makes the code clearer, and I don't think that solution makes the code clearer in this case.

Comment: Can you give an example?  Why must you use a while loop?

Comment: Are you looking for something like [itertools.count?](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.count)

Comment: Do you mean while(i<100) { i++ } kind of loop ?

Comment: @BrenBarn: Possibly there is another termination condition besides reaching the end of the iterable. `break` could be used but it's better self-documenting to have the significant termination conditions of a loop in the header.

Comment: Presumably the OP is looking for something like `while True: do_stuff() if condition: break` and then `print(times_loop_ran)`

Comment: @BrenBarn I added an example. In any case, `while` is often useful - there is a reason they included it in the language.

Comment: @morningstar I don't see how you would do the same thing with a `for` without making it uglier and less comprehensible.

Comment: @FredrikPihl Can you explain how `itertools.count` helps in this case?

Comment: If you want the code to be clear, it's hard to beat making the counter explicit.

Comment: Yes, since "explicit is better than implicit", I'm not sure how the desired but unspecified solution is being repeatedly claimed to be "Pythonic". If you want to both count and print the number of times you do something, I'm not sure what could be more "Pythonic" than having a counter variable.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths and @BrenBarn I consider it more "pythonic" to use  `enumerate` with a `for` loop than using a counter variable. It is more pythonic (in my view) since `enumerate` is part of python and exists specifically for this task. If there would be a similar mechanism for `while`, I would use the same reasoning. Currently, though, it seems there isn't.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Improvement (in readability, I'd say) to Ignacio's answer:

```
x = 0
for c in itertools.takewhile(lambda c: x < 10, itertools.count()):
    x = int(raw_input())
    print x, c
```

Advantages:

- Only the while loop condition is in the loop header, not the side-effect raw_input.
- The loop condition can depend on any condition that a normal while loop could. It's not necessary to "import" the variables referenced into the takewhile, as they are already visible in the lambda scope. Additionally it can depend on the count if you want, though not in this case.
- Simplified: enumerate no longer appears at all.

Answer (score 6):

Again with the [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html)...

```
import itertools

for c, x in enumerate(
    itertools.takewhile(lambda v: v < 10,
      (int(raw_input()) for z in itertools.count())
    )
  ):
  print c, x
```

Comment: Interesting, but I wouldn't say this makes the code clearer either! :-)

Comment: Actually, it's not quite functionally the same. The original code will print the 10 or larger value, but this one will not.

Comment: Yes, but I think this is a good example of how making the algorithm clearer and more simple allows the programmer to analyze and then actually improve upon the initial specification.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about `itertools.takewhile()`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want *zero* initialization before the `while` loop, you can use a [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) with a counter:

```
class Singleton(object):
    _instance = None
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if not cls._instance:
            cls._instance = super(Singleton, cls).__new__(
                                cls, *args, **kwargs)
            cls.count=0
        else:
            cls.count+=1                            
        return cls._instance
```

Then there will only be one instance of Singleton and each additional instance just adds one:

```
>>> Singleton().count    # initial instance
0
>>> Singleton().count
1
>>> Singleton().count
2
>>> Singleton().count
3
```

Then your while loop becomes:

```
while Singleton():
    x=int(raw_input('x: '))
    if x>10: break

print 'While loop executed',Singleton().count,'times'
```

Entering `1,2,3,11` it prints:

```
x: 1
x: 2
x: 3
x: 11
While loop executed 4 times
```

If you do not mind a single line initialization before the `while` loop, you can just subclass an interator:

```
import collections
class WhileEnum(collections.Iterator):
    def __init__(self,stop=None):
        self.stop=stop
        self.count=0

    def next(self):    # '__next__' on Py 3, 'next' on Py 2
        if self.stop is not None:
            self.remaining=self.stop-self.count
            if self.count>=self.stop: return False
        self.count+=1    
        return True

    def __call__(self):
        return self.next()
```

Then your while loop becomes:

```
enu=WhileEnum()
while enu():
    i=int(raw_input('x: '))
    if i>10: break

print enu.count
```

I think the second is the far better approach. You can have multiple enumerators and you can also set a limit on how many loops to go:

```
limited_enum=WhileEnum(5)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to do what you want in the exact way you want it. If I understand right, you want a `while` loop that increments a counter each time through, without actually exposing a visible counter outside the scope of the loop. I think the way to do this would be to rewrite your `while` loop as a nonterminating `for` loop, and check the end condition manually. For your example code:

```
import itertools

x = 0
for c in itertools.count():
    x = int(raw_input())
    print x, c
    if x >= 10:
        break
```

The problem is that fundamentally you're doing iteration, with the counter. If you don't want to expose that counter, it needs to come from the loop construct. Without defining a new function, you're stuck with a standard loop and an explicit check.

On the other hand, you could probably also define a generator for this. You'd still be iterating, but you could at least wrap the check up in the loop construct.

Comment: Thanks. I generally tend to avoid that kind of `for` loops and I think it is not very pythonic. It would be probably clearer to just keep the `while` and the counter variable. Let's see if someone comes up with a different solution.