# Is there a pythonic way to do a while-loop with an index?

Tags: python

Is there a more Pythonic way to write the code beneath, so that it iterates over some condition but also keeps an index of the iterations?

```
def TrieMatching(text, trie):
    match_locations = []
    location = 0
    while text:
        if PrefixTrieMatching(text, trie):
            match_locations.append(location)
        text = text[1:]
        location += 1
```

Comment: What do you think this line does: `text[1:]` ?

Comment: That was a mistake; I meant `text = text[1:]`

Comment: I wonder if this would be better suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17137490/pythonic-enumeration-of-while-loop

Comment: Presumably your function should also `return match_locations`?

Comment: @Robᵩ Good question! In this particular case, I'd say it fits about evenly on both sites. This is a specific enough question to be on-topic on Stack Overflow, I believe. For future reference, you might want to read [A Guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 5):

I'm always fond of list comprehensions.

```
def TrieMatching(text, trie):
    match_locations = [
        location
        for location in range(len(text))
        if PrefixTrieMatch(text[location:],trie)
    ]
```

Comment: Presumably you omitted `return` because the question also did, but it does render the function less than useful

Comment: Meh. If your list comprehension has to split many lines, just use a for loop.

Answer (score 4):

You are always increasing `i` so just use range:

```
def TrieMatching(text, trie):
    match_locations = []
    for i in range(len(text)):
        if PrefixTrieMatching(text[i:], trie):
            match_locations.append(i)
```

Comment: In this case, no need to  reassign `text = text[1:]`. Just switch to `if PrefixTrieMatching(text[i:], trie)`  is probably better.

Comment: @mehtunguh, yes, it is more there to show that you actually need to reassign text to actually change what the name points to. `text[i:]` in the OP's code is not doing much

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever heard the old saying "Give a man a hammer and suddenly all his problems look like nails"? The `while` loop is not a hammer.

Why use a `while` loop at all? If I am correct your problem can be stated without reference to them as "produce a list of the locations of all suffixes of `text` which match a given `trie`".

This can be written as a list comprehension:

```
def TrieMatching(text, trie):
   return [l for l in range(len(text)) if PrefixTrieMatching(text[l:], trie)]
```

I added a `return` as there is little point in computing a value only to retain no reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

`enumerate()` is a great way to iterate over something and get an index as well. It returns an iterable that yields tuples of (counter, value)

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate

From the docs:

```
>>> seasons = ['Spring', 'Summer', 'Fall', 'Winter']
>>> list(enumerate(seasons))
[(0, 'Spring'), (1, 'Summer'), (2, 'Fall'), (3, 'Winter')]
```

So you can use it in a for loop really easily:

```
for (i,season) in enumerate(seasons):
     print "{} {}".format(i,season)
```

prints:

```
0 Spring
1 Summer
2 Fall
3 Winer
```

Comment: But you will find it you try to use it in this particular problem that it doesn't help very much.

Comment: @holdenweb it actually answers the question that is asked very well, even though it isn't very good for the specific example given.

Comment: @mehtungu Thanks for your comment. The issue would seem to be whether it does answer that question. I should like to see an actual answer to the question (_"Is there a more Pythonic way"_) using `enumerate` before I delete that comment (which, if wrong, I will happily do - I have no interest in promoting false technical information and I'm not infallible). Unfortunately my downvote is now locked in unless the A is edited.

Answer (score 0):

`enumerate` is often used for tracking the index in a for loop. Here is an example of how to use it.

```
for i, elem in enumerate("abc"):
    print(i, elem)

0 a
1 b
2 c
```

In your example, you aren't using the `elem` as in the above case, so `enumerate` may not be the best solution. You should probably either try using `range` or stick with the `while` loop you already have.

```
for location in range(len(text)):
    if PrefixTrieMatching(text[location:], trie):
        match_locations.append(location)
```

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't necessarily use this, but `itertools.count()` is `[1, 2, 3, ...]`.

```
import itertools
for i in itertools.count():
    ...
```

Comment: Please give solutions as answers, not suggestions